# An anchor over image not clickable in IE 10 but works in IE 11, Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a tile created like:

```
<div>
  <img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/BMW-i8-Mirrorless-cameras-101-876x535.jpg" width="400" alt="img" />

  <a href="http://www.google.com"></a>
</div>
```

with css:

```
div {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Or jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fvguL0hn/

You'll see that you cannot click over that image, in IE 10, but in IE 11 works and other browsers too.

If you mouse out image then you can click, but you go back with cursor to image, then the pointer cursor becomes normal one and you cannot click like somehow anchor is hidden back to the image even I changed `z-index`.

This happens only in IE 10 ...

What is my mistake ? I changed the `z-index` but same thing.

Answer (score 0):

why not do this?

```
<div>
  <a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://blog.caranddriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/BMW-i8-Mirrorless-cameras-101-876x535.jpg" width="400" alt="img" /></a>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew that but I'm curious why that happens when both elements are absolute ?

Comment: I'm guessing because the anchor tag has no size. Give it a height and width. Ie 10 must be treating it like its zero pixels in size so you will never be able to click on it

Comment: Your anchor tag has nothing in it to click on. Like I said I'm guessing ie 10 is treating it like it is zero pixels by zero pixels

Comment: The idea is that I want a container to be clickable ... a container might have a lot of elements... I want to overlap an anchor over it.

Comment: Then put the anchor tag around the div. an anchor tag with nothing in it isn't a container. You need something inside the anchor tag for someone to click on

Comment: Just to be sure, you want everything inside the container to go the the same anchor link?

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's why I used that approach with position absolute without using javascript solution